# Problems in compiling C files

Tags: c, gcc

I have these three files which I'm trying to link together. It's a didactic example, I tried different combinations compiling the three files but I have no clue what' s wrong. Even if something with this trivial code is wrong.

What I'm trying to understand is how to separate in different files the declaration of a function in order to include it from an header file in the main one. Or at least this is what I figured out. My teacher set the example in order to have an .h file and two .c files: Here they are...

foo.c

```
int foo(int x){
return x==42 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

foo.h

```
extern int foo(int);
```

use-foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main(){
printf("foo(42) == %d \n", foo(42));
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can guide my through this, I don't need a different solution , please help me with these 3 only files because the aim of the teacher was this.

Comment: compile with gcc -Wall use-foo.c foo.c, to get a.out and execute it with ./a.out, but make sure the foo.h is in current directory where you are calling gcc.

Comment: You don't need extern int foo(int); functions in C are automatic extern, just do this int foo(int);

Comment: `gcc use-foo.c foo.c` or `gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o` then `gcc use-foo.c foo.o`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY he needs at least to turn on one of the compiler warning. He can't walk with the Lion with eyes closed. lol

Comment: You should include `foo.h` in `foo.c` so that the compiler cross-checks that the definition of `foo()` matches the declaration used by other parts of the code.  That's wholly unrelated to your linking problem, but is important when you're working with larger examples.  If the function is used outside its own source file, it should be declared in a header and the header should be included where the function is defined and everywhere it is used.  If the function is not used outside its own source file, it should be static.

Comment: @SeekAddo It seems like a independent of the at least his problem. LOL

Comment: I think I misinterpeted the slides of my teacher. Everything works if I append the code of foo.c inside foo.h . Thanks everyone.

Comment: No; no; no!  Do not include the code of `foo.c` inside `foo.h`.  That is completely the wrong way to do it!  All else apart, if you have two source files that use `foo()` — `use-foo.c` and `otherfile.c` — and you need to link both those together, you will get `foo()` multiply defined and your program won't link.  You must keep the implementation separate from the declaration (so keep `foo.c` separate from `foo.h`).

Comment: Following your comments I 'd have still 3 files but the content in foo.h must be copied on top of foo.c is it right?

Comment: I'd like to attach my slides to make you understand what I'm reading here, but are written in italian.

Comment: No; what's in the header stays in the header.  You add `#include "foo.h"` to the top of `foo.c`, just like you have `#include "foo.h"` in `use-foo.c`.  And, ideally, you have no headers before `#include "foo.h"` in `foo.c` which means you automatically check that the header is self-contained (anyone using it can write `#include "foo.h"` without needing to include anything else and won't run into compilation errors).

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it with the command :

```
gcc -o use-foo use-foo.c foo.c
```

Then you'll be able to run it with the command :

```
./use-foo
```

Just be sure that all your files are in the same directory, that you call gcc from that directory and that gcc is installed on your system.

A couple more advices on including files, and cross-compiling : 
All your header files (like foo.h) should have include guards, like that

```
#ifndef __FOO__
#define __FOO__

int foo (int);

#endif
```

that'll prevent the compiler from adding your header file more than once in your code.

Another advice would be to include foo.h in your foo.c code as well.

Comment: You don't need include guards if your header only contains function/variable declarations.